# Setting the 'default folder' that opens when attaching a document in Mac Mail on El Capitan?

Tags: macos, email

Is it possible to set the 'default folder' that opens when attaching a document in Mac Mail on El Capitan?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/). It does exactly what you want by defining default folders for any application you want.

Also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/161499/498587) may help you.

Comment: If I'm reading the question right, it seems to be asking about the default browse location that opens to select a file for attachment, rather than the save location.

Comment: Default Folder X doesn't differentiate between saving and opening. So setting a default folder for Mail would open to said folder in both instances - whether it be saving or opening/attaching a file.